# tinymce editor on joomla. Install plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, tinymce

I've download a plugin for tinymce editor for Joomla. I've pasted all files inside the plugin folder of tinymce under Joomla. After, the readme claims:

```
Then in the tinymce init function make sure you include the Bold lines.

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
auto_resize:false,
extended_valid_elements: "textarea[name|class|cols|rows]", 
remove_linebreaks : false, 
width:720,
plugins : 'preview,codehighlighting',
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "right",
theme_advanced_buttons1_add : " fontselect,fontsizeselect,zoom",
theme_advanced_buttons2_add : "preview,separator,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3_add_before : "tablecontrols, codehighlighting"

});
</script>
```

where do I need to paste that code?

Comment: could you provide a link to the plugin you have downloaded please.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/nawaf/archive/2008/04/06/syntaxhighlighter-plugin-for-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions are poorly written in the site you provided therefore I'm not too sure where you have to inset that code in your question.

I would personally use the [Code Highlighter](http://www.codeis.com/codehighlighter) Joomla extension. We have used his on our site and it works like a charm.

Comment: so are we ;) the extension is 2.5 compatible

Answer (score 2):

You need to place this kind of code where your tinymce configaration is stored / read from.
To find out where this is - [here is a tutorial with detailed explanations.](http://joomla.boastworthy.com/how-to/21-configure-the-tinymce-editor-in-joomla.pdf)